# Configuring Startup file for f# asp.net core project is giving strange errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, f#

I'm trying to get started on an ASP.NET F# project, following a mvc type pattern.

I'm using the rider IDE, since I'm running linux. The rider IDE has ASP.NET MVC templates, out of the box, so to get started with this project, I choose the ASP.NET Core web application template.

I now have a `Program.fs` file and a `Startup.fs`, and I can run the project and view a little helloworld-page in the browser.

But now I want to setup the routing such that I can route to controllers.

For doing this, I looked at the skeleton of a C# MVC project, and tried to emulate the `Startup` file.

My startup file now looks like this:

```
namespace WebApplication1

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder

open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

type Startup() =
    

  
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddAuthorization()

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    member _.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =
        if env.IsDevelopment() then
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
                     
        app.UseHttpsRedirection() |> ignore
        app.UseStaticFiles() |> ignore
        app.UseRouting() |> ignore
        app.UseAuthorization)() |> ignore
    
        app.UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" ) |> ignore
            ) |> ignore
```

Now, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. Please add EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting' inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.

So it's complaining that I'm not calling `IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting` in the configure method.

This is strange to me, as I actually am making such a call.

Does anyone know how I could rewrite this to enable routing to controllers?

**EDIT**

It has been pointed out to me that I was missing parentheses. I fixed this, and was then informed by the compiler that I was also missing a call `services.AddAuthorization()`  inside of `ConfigureServices`. I now fixed this, and the code above so it correponds to what I'm running.

Now when I run it, I get:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling
  'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to      'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
```

This doesnt quite make sense to me, since I have such a call in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: You seem to have forgot the parentheses: UseRouting() and UseAuthorization()

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your `ConfigureServices` isn't being called at all, because it has the wrong signature. Try this instead:

```ml
member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddAuthorization() |> ignore
```

Unfortunately, `ignore` is crucial in this case. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620484/why-webapi-authorization-service-could-not-be-found-in-netcore-3-1) is essentially the same thing.